# Parar requisição com Jquery ao atualizar a página ou clicar em algum link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou usando long polling com PHP + JQuery, quando o usuário entra no site é aberta uma conexão em segundo plano com o servidor através do Jquery dessa forma:

```
var req  = $.post //(resto do codigo aqui).
```

Essa conexão fica aberta por 20 segundos e depois é fechada automaticamente.

Bom como vocês podem perceber eu gravo em uma variável para poder abortar a requisição com o `req.abort();`

Mas eu queria abortar ela apenas quando o usuário atualizasse a página ou desse um clique em algum link da página, pois quando ele faz isso o site só "responde" depois que a requisição é terminada, dessa forma o usuário teria de esperar 20 segundos + o tempo que o site poderia vir a demorar para por exemplo upar uma imagem após o fim da requisição, então eu gostaria de saber se tem como não fazer uma nova requisição quando ele der uma atualizada nela?

Ps: Usei como teste o `setTimeout` colocando ele para dar um `req.abort();` depois de x segundos, e a requisição foi cancelada normalmente, então como não tinha nenhuma nova conexão aberta com o servidor aguardando resposta, quando a página foi atualizada ela não demorou 20 segundos para dar procedência, mas isso não é viável, visto que estou fazendo verificações em tempo real rsrs

Código atual do arquivo js abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
pegaNotificacoes();
});

var totalnot = 0;
var totalparc = 0;

function limpatotal()
{
totalparc = 0;
$('#notifinum').html("");
}

function pegaNotificacoes(timestamp)
{

var data = {};

if (typeof timestamp != 'undefined')
 data.timestamp = timestamp;

var req  = $.post('controllers/longpolling.php', data, function(res){
 
 for(i in res.notificacoes)
 {
  
  if (totalnot == 0)
  {
   $('#notificacao').html("");
   $('#notificacao').prepend("<div style='height: 60px;' class='notificacao'><a href='"+res.notificacoes[i].not_link+"&notid="+res.notificacoes[i].not_codigo+"'>"+res.notificacoes[i].not_assunto+"</a></div>");
  }
  else
  {
   $('#notificacao').prepend("<div style='height: 60px;' class='notificacao'><a href='"+res.notificacoes[i].not_link+"&notid="+res.notificacoes[i].not_codigo+"'>"+res.notificacoes[i].not_assunto+"</a></div>");
  }
  
  totalnot = totalnot + 1; 
  totalparc = totalparc + 1; 
  $('#notifinum').html("").fadeOut('slow', 'linear');
  $('#notifinum').html(totalparc).fadeIn('fast', 'linear');
  
  if (totalnot > 1)
  {
   if ($("#notificacao").height() < 350)
   {
    var altura = ($("#notificacao").height()) + 55;
    $("#notificacao").height(altura);
   }
  }
 }
 
 pegaNotificacoes(res.timestamp);
 
}, 'json');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara pelo que eu entendi você pode verificar se ocorreu o evento **reload**, conforme o exemplo:

```
if(location.reload)
{
    req.abort();
}
```

Assim caso ele ocorra vc chama sua função que aborta a requisição.

No caso do click em um link, você pode adicionar na tag  `<a>` no html uma classe, por exemplo:

`<a class='abortar'> Aborte a requisição </a>`

E utilizando o jquery você pode pegar o click desta tag com o exemplo:

```
$('a').on('click','.abortar',function()
{
   req.abort();
});
```

Comment: A ideia do Marcos Henrique funcionou direitinho, ta cancelando a requisição toda vez que atualiza a página ou clica em um link exatamente da forma que eu queria, vlw parceiro :D :)

Comment: que bom que funcionou cara, estamos ai pra ajudar mesmo!